# Blender compositing conflict

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am having a huge problem with compositing an effect I want. I finally finished animating, now I'm heading to compositing, and I got Glare on before I started animation, because it's difficult to deal with trying to get the desired parameter. Here is my node setup so far. (Note: I will be adding multiple effects than just two.)

[image: obviously done compositing, and Glare is dismissed, Lens Distortion works.]

I tried so many things, yet to find out what the problem is. I even searched it up. I tried another composite. Like Transform. Still gets dismissed. What's the problem here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use only one composite node

Comment: I cant use only one, only one effect can be applied onto a composite node, I cant do two. Got another suggestion?

Comment: @cegaton i cant use only one, only one effect can be applied onto a composite node, I cant do two. Got another suggestion?

Comment: To mix things... use mix nodes . the composite node is the output

Comment: @cegaton I still couldnt get this to work...

Comment: @cegaton Its not working. The lens distortion is not going onto the glare. Is this a problem?

Comment: @cegaton Thanks! I didn't know this was something so simple. I completely forgot how because I haven't made a Blender only thing in a long time. Thanks so much. I could give you diamonds right now.

Answer (score 3):

Use only one composite node. Think of it as the output image.

The other nodes can be added after each other or in parallel and mixed in a variety of ways:

[image]

[image]